# Given an element, returning the inorder rank of it an in a binary search tree with only two parameters

Tags: c++

I have a solution here, but I'm not too fond of it because I feel like it can be done better.

```
template <typename Comparable>
bool AugmentedBinarySearchTree<Comparable>::Rank(const Comparable& x, BinaryNode* t, int* nodesVisited) const {
  if (t == NULL) {
    return false;
  }
  if (Rank(x, t->m_left, nodesVisited)) {
    return true;
  }
  *nodesVisited += 1;
  if (t->m_element == x) {
    return true;
  }
  return Rank(x, t->m_right, nodesVisited);
}
```

My biggest stumbling block was finding way to both confirm the node actually existed and also returning its rank.

I started with this method signature

```
int BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::Rank(const Comparable& x, BinaryNode* t) const {
```

but in the end I had to make the method return a bool and add an extra parameter to keep track to where the program was in the traversal.

Is there any way to do this without the nodesVisited parameter?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to return false in case you can't find x at all? Why not just return a negative number in that case? Then you can keep an int return type, no?

Comment: @sunny Yeah but it's basically the same thing as a bool at that point anyways isn't it? Negative = false and Positive = true. If I tried to store that state in nodesVisited, which I did try, it'll screw up the value I need returned.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I thought your desire was to return the int count rather than the bool true or false? can't you do that once you return a negative value for x in the case of a null node? It seems like nothing else would need to change.

Comment: Right, but that would still require the third parameter. I guess my real question then, and I'll edit this, is it possible to achieve this with only two parameters (without nodesVisited)?

Comment: @AR7 In similar situations STL returns a `std::pair<bool, int>`. Follow the suit.

Comment: @vnp That's typically what I would do in python/javascript but didn't know if it was idiomatic in C++. Is it better to use std::pair even though it requires you to include more libraries?

Comment: @AR7 Don't worry about including templates. No code size/performance penalties. BTW, idiomatic Python would raise a `KeyError` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the following approach. Split up `Rank` into a public-facing member function and a private-facing member function. The private one's signature is:

```
template <typename Value>
std::pair<bool, int> RankImpl(BinaryNode* tree, const Value& value);
```

The public one is:

```
template <typename Value>
boost::optional<int> Rank(BinaryNode* tree, const Value& value);
```

(Secondarily, I flipped the order of your arguments, provided better names for them, and am not limiting the value we're looking for to be a `Comparable`. Rather, anything that is equality-comparable to `Comparable` should suffice).

The idea of using [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) is that it, as a return type, already encompasses what you want in a single type - it tells you if there is or isn't a value (i.e. was `value` found or not) and if there is a value, what it is (i.e. its rank). We however privately still need a value even in the `false` case, hence the `pair` helper function.

Altogether:

```
template <typename Value>
boost::optional<int> Rank(BinaryNode* tree, const Value& value)
{
    auto pr = RankImpl(tree, value);
    if (pr.first) {
        return pr.second;
    }
    else {
        return boost::none;
    }
}

template <typename Value>
std::pair<bool, int> RankImpl(BinaryNode* tree, const Value& value)
{
    if (!tree) {
        return {false, 0};
    }

    auto left = RankImpl(tree->left, value);
    if (left.first) {
        return left;
    }
    else if (tree->m_element == value) {
        return {true, left.second + 1};
    }        
    else {
        auto right = RankImpl(tree->right, value);
        return {right.first, left.second + 1 + right.second};
    }
}
```

Comment: As I've gotten more into programming I've heard the NULL isn't a great idea, so is boost::optional the way around dealing with NULL? Also any reason you prefer auto over the actual type in this case?

Comment: @AR7 I don't know what `NULL` has to do with anything. There's no `NULL` to deal with? `auto` is just less to type and will definitely give me the correct type.

Comment: I guess I was making a connection to something that wasn't here. Thank you for your help!